# Saving weights to memory in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am using python2.7 and tensorflow and need to save the weights based on the results of the next computation. Therefore I need to temporarily save the previous weights, one way is by using:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(...variables...)
saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=step)
```

But the problem is that the weights get saved to the disk, which is quite slow and adds up over time because i have to temporarily save the weights for every step. Is there a way to temporarily save the weights to the memory?
Another way would be by declaring the weight variables as placeholders, saving the weights after each step to other dummy weight variables and then passing the temporary weight variables back to the placeholders for every step. But that is very unsatisfying.

Comment: Why do you need to save the weights anyways? Can you simply just set reuse = True for the weights?

Comment: Here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq#building_training_eval_and_inference_graphs, it suggests that we should "build many graphs" each for one purpose. The trick relies on saving and loading to share the weights between graphs.

Comment: How you got an solution? I want to save/load every step too.